# Is it possible to configure CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in Django 4 to allow access from any IP address?

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have found several posts regarding this but did not find what I need.

I have upgraded Django from 2.x to 4.x for an Angular/Django web app which will be packaged and distributed to users that will install in different hosts and domains.
MOST IMPORTANTLY, they would need to access the app from multiple locations on a serving port via browser (i.e. HTTP://whereAppIsInstalled:PORT).

This used to work in Django 2 without CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS and with the settings below:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

All the answers say that I need to add those hosts, IPs, or subdomains to the `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` list in settings.py. This works, but impractical in my case since I don't know all the hosts and IPs.

I also noticed in [Django documentation that we could add "HTTP://..." to CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins), but this does not seem to work. I have to explicitly list all the IPs of the machines I am using to access the app.

***What should I do in this situation? How do I make sure that my app allows requests from all IPs?***